# Hover isn't working on custom button

Tags: css

I have checked everything in dev console, but couldn't find any conflicts in my styles. For some reason css pseudo class doesn't work on my custom style button.

I have recreated this problem in [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/hfwMzwzJ8oBxqrrEYoc2?p=preview)

Also here is my css code.

```
.blinked-in {
    opacity:0;  /* make things invisible upon start */
    -webkit-animation:blinkedIn ease-in 1;
    -moz-animation:blinkedIn ease-in 1;
    animation:blinkedIn ease-in 1;

    -webkit-animation-fill-mode:forwards;
    -moz-animation-fill-mode:forwards;
    animation-fill-mode:forwards;

    -webkit-animation-duration:1100ms;
    -moz-animation-duration:1100ms;
    animation-duration:1100ms;
}

.blinked-in:hover {
    background-color: #27a5d2 !important;
    color: white;
}

@-webkit-keyframes blinkedIn {
    from {
        opacity:0;
        color: black;
        background-color: #27a5d2;
    }
    to {
        opacity: 1;
        border: 1px solid #27a5d2;
        background-color: #e1f4f9;
        color: black;
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes blinkedIn {
    from {
        opacity:0;
        color: black;
        background-color: #27a5d2;
    }
    to {
        opacity: 1;
        border: 1px solid #27a5d2;
        background-color: #e1f4f9;
        color: black;
    }
}
@keyframes blinkedIn {
    from {
        opacity:0;
        color: black;
        background-color: #27a5d2;
    }
    to {
        opacity: 1;
        border: 1px solid #27a5d2;
        background-color: #e1f4f9;
        color: black;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this what you're going for? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mWyeNd

Comment: @MichaelCoker exactly this one! So I just need to put hover style behind @keyframe?

Comment: @antonyboom I'll submit it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `opacity: 0` and the `animation-fill-mode: forwards` property so that the element doesn't try to maintain that state after the animation is done, then override bootstrap's `:hover` CSS for `.btn-default` by either changing your selector to have higher specificity or using `!important`

```css
.blinked-in {
  -webkit-animation: blinkedIn ease-in 1;
  -moz-animation: blinkedIn ease-in 1;
  animation: blinkedIn ease-in 1;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1100ms;
  -moz-animation-duration: 1100ms;
  animation-duration: 1100ms;
}


/* make keyframes that tell the start state and the end state of our object */

@-webkit-keyframes blinkedIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    color: black;
    background-color: #27a5d2;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    border: 1px solid #27a5d2;
    background-color: #e1f4f9;
    color: black;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes blinkedIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    color: black;
    background-color: #27a5d2;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    border: 1px solid #27a5d2;
    background-color: #e1f4f9;
    color: black;
  }
}

@keyframes blinkedIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    color: black;
    background-color: #27a5d2;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    border: 1px solid #27a5d2;
    background-color: #e1f4f9;
    color: black;
  }
}

.blinked-in:hover {
  background-color: #27a5d2 !important;
  color: white!important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Bootstrap, from Twitter</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="author" content="" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <button class="btn btn-default blinked-in"> TEST BUTTON</button>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Awesome! I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I just don't understand your code, but you don't **need** `animation` to make hover effects, but you can control the speed of changes with `transition`:

```
.blinked-in {
    transition: all 1s;
    -moz-transition: all 1s;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s;
        color: white;
        border: 1px solid transparent;
    background-color: black;
}
.blinked-in:hover {
    border: 1px solid #27a5d2;
    background-color: #e1f4f9;
    color: black;
}
```

Demo: http://codepen.io/dimaspante/pen/NpPGQb